# talend - ignore row if all columns except first have no value

Tags: filter, talend

I have the following table:

```
date  c1 c2 ... cn
01/01  2  3  ... 4   
01/02       ...
01/03       ...
```

What is the easiest way to filter out the rows where all except the date column have no value? (in this example, the rows with date 01/02 and 01/03)

Comment: read the table  using corresponding tDBinputcomponent, then either you can use tFilterRow or tMap and add condition like below input_flow.date !=null && !(input_flow.c1 == null && input_row.c2 == null......)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to setup an input component and change its schema a bit by saying in the schema definition that a value is mandatory, and these records should be ignored